# Как отсортировать файлы по их типу в linux?

Tags: linux

Нужно вывести топ 10 типов файлов в папке и под папках. Уже сломал голову как это сделать. То есть на выводе должно быть название 10 типов, которые встречаются чаще всего и количество файлов к каждому типу.

Благодарю за ответы!

Comment: вам нужен именно тип самого файла, или, как я догадываюсь, суффикс его имени?

Comment: Вот правильный вопрос задаёт @alexanderbarakin. Вы по содержимому (читай: mime-type) хотите, или просто по **условному** расширению?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна вот такая конструкция

```
find . -f | egrep -o '\.[^.\//]+' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n  -k 1 -r | head
```

все запутанно, но разберем по командам.

- Вначале `find . -f` найдет все файлы.
- `egrep -o '\.[^.\//]+'` - вырежет с каждой строки конец, где хранится расширение.
- потом отсортируем, чтобы `uniq -c` смог посчитать количество (это известная конструкция)
- а потом ещё раз отсортируем список вида "кол-во расширение"
- и возмем первые 10, как нужно по заданию.

Но типы файлов можно определить и с помощью команды file. Вот решение, оно теперь должно выглядеть просто

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file -i -b | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n  -r  | head
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!

Comment: И это неверный подход. Он, конечно, даст желаемый результат в 99% случаев, но часть файлов окажется отнесена не к той категории.

Comment: В любом случае найдутся файлы, которые сложно классифицировать.  Да и "особых случаев" есть много. Но на то мозг и дан человеку, чтобы анализировать и понимать.

Comment: @0andriy, какая часть? Все файлы без расширения потеряются? Или ты о том, что реальный тип может не соответствовать расширению?

Comment: @qwertiy, да, я о mime-type vs. extension.